# CentOS 6 and Devtoolset-3

Tags: centos

Trying to install C++ from [Devtoolset-3](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-3/) to my CentOS6 system I've ran into dependencies problem:

```
bash-4.2# yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.dhakacom.com
* extras: mirror.dhakacom.com
* updates: centosr4.centos.org
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-3-gcc = 4.9.2-6.el6 for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-3-libstdc++-devel = 4.9.2-6.el6 for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-3-binutils >= 2.22.52.0.1 for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-3-runtime for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package devtoolset-3-libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package devtoolset-3-binutils.x86_64 0:2.24-18.el6 will be installed
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package devtoolset-3-runtime.x86_64 0:3.1-12.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64 (rhscl-devtoolset-3-epel-6-x86_64)
        Requires: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64 (rhscl-devtoolset-3-epel-6-x86_64)
        Requires: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64 (rhscl-devtoolset-3-epel-6-x86_64)
        Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64 (rhscl-devtoolset-3-epel-6-x86_64)
        Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

As for me it looks like a bug: SCL should contain updated packages for that libs... but maybe I've missed smth?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/1088612/upgrade-gcc-to-gcc-4-9-in-rhel-7 about `compat-libgmp` and `compat-libmpfr` -

Answer (score 0):

The two libraries from your error output are provided by mpfr and gmp, which are in the base repository.

```
$ repoquery --whatprovides 'libmpfr.so.1()(64bit)'
mpfr-0:2.4.1-6.el6.x86_64
$ repoquery --whatprovides 'libgmp.so.3()(64bit)'
gmp-0:4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.x86_64
```

If yum can't see them, it is possible that are excluding them in the yum configuration.

Comment: No that is default install and I didn't do anything w/ `yum` configs...

Comment: Something is different on your machine from "default".  I just spun up a CentOS 6 docker container, installed centos-release-scl, then installed devtoolset-3-gcc-c++ without issue.